# Function about the product between 2 Matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic, allocation, multiplication

I have a problem in running my code because the function that I made to have the multiplication between two matrices is still not working even if I have tried different solutions, probably I am missing something important about pointers in the function.

Because the code stops running near the call of the function itself, excuse me if this post is not all correctly done or written but it is my first post on this site.

Here's my code I hope someone could help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXR 50
#define MAXC 50

void printmatrix(int **matrix, int r, int c) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("-%d-", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void matrixprod(int **matrix3, int matrix1[][MAXC], int matrix2[][MAXC], int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2) {
    int i, h, k;
    h = k = 0;

    matrix3[h][k]=0;
    for (i = 0; i < c1; i++) {
        matrix3[h][k] += (matrix1[h][i] * matrix2[i][k]);
    }
    k++;
    while (k < c2) {
        matrix3[h][k] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < c1; i++) {
            matrix3[h][k] += (matrix1[h][i] * matrix2[i][k]);
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (h < r1) {
        h++;
        k = 0;
        matrix3[h][k] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < c1; i++) {
            matrix3[h][k] += (matrix1[h][i] * matrix2[i][k]);
        }
        k++;
        while (k < c2) {
            matrix3[h][k] = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < c1; i++) {
                matrix3[h][k] += (matrix1[h][i] * matrix2[i][k]);
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, j, h, k;
    int r1, r2, c1, c2;
    printf("Inserire la dimensione R delle righe e C delle colonne:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r1, &c1);
    int matrix1[r1][c1];
    printf("\n**RIEMPIRE LA MATRICE 1 **\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Inserire la dimensione R delle righe e C delle colonne:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r2, &c2);
    int matrix2[r2][c2];
    printf("\n**RIEMPIRE LA MATRICE 2 **\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix2[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int **matrix3;
    matrix3 = malloc(r1 * sizeof(*matrix3));
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        matrix3[i] = malloc(c2 * sizeof(*matrix3[i]));
    }
    if (r1 != c2) {
        printf("PROD NON ESEGUIBILE");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n****PROD MATRIX*****\n");
    matrixprod(matrix3, matrix1, matrix2, r1, c1, r2, c2);
    printmatrix(matrix3, r1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your indentation needs work - I cannot tell quickly where main() begins/ends.  Please insert a blank line between functions and indent the first level of brackets to make your code easily readable.

Comment: My exercise goal is: Write a function that calculates the product between two
matrices, storing the result in an allocated matrix
dynamically

Comment: Do you have link to this exercise? I want to try to solve it too.

Comment: Sorry but no, only that phrase , it's in a set of written exercises without a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The 2D matrix sizes are inconsistent between the definition in the `main` function and the declaration in the `matrixprod` function.  You should define the source matrices `matrix1` and `matrix2` as `int matrix1[r2][MAXC];` or `int matrix1[MAXR][MAXC];`
- You can simplify the code: the first row does not need special casing, and using classic `for` loops is less error prone than `while` loops.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXR 50
#define MAXC 50

void printmatrix(int **matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf(" %d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void matrixprod(int **matrix3, int matrix1[][MAXC], int matrix2[][MAXC],
                int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2) {
    if (c1 != r2) {
        printf("matrix geometries are incompatible\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            int p = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++) {
                 p += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
            }
            matrix3[i][j] = p;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int r1, r2, c1, c2;
    printf("Inserire la dimensione R delle righe e C delle colonne:\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &r1, &c1) != 2 || r1 <= 0 || c1 <= 0 || r1 > MAXR || c1 > MAXC) {
        printf("invalid matrix size\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int matrix1[MAXR][MAXC];
    printf("\n**RIEMPIRE LA MATRICE 1 **\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c1; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Inserire la dimensione R delle righe e C delle colonne:\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &r2, &c2) != 2 || r2 <= 0 || c2 <= 0 || r2 > MAXR || c2 > MAXC) {
        printf("invalid matrix size\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int matrix2[MAXR][MAXC];
    printf("\n**RIEMPIRE LA MATRICE 2 **\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < r2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &matrix2[i][j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    if (c1 != r2) {
        printf("PROD NON ESEGUIBILE");
        exit(1);
    }
    int **matrix3 = malloc(r1 * sizeof(*matrix3));
    if (matrix3 == NULL)
        return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        matrix3[i] = malloc(c2 * sizeof(*matrix3[i]));
        if (matrix3[i] == NULL)
            return 1;
    }
    printf("\n****PROD MATRIX*****\n");
    matrixprod(matrix3, matrix1, matrix2, r1, c1, r2, c2);
    printmatrix(matrix3, r1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you could allocate indirect matrices for all 3 operands, thus removing the `MAXC` and `MAXR` constraints:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void free_matrix(int **matrix, int rows) {
    /* free a dynamic matrix */
    if (matrix != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            free(matrix[i]);
        }
        free(matrix);
    }
}

int **new_matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    /* allocate a dynamic matrix initialized to 0 */
    int **matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(*matrix));
    if (matrix != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            matrix[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof(*matrix[i]));
            if (matrix[i] == NULL) {
                free_matrix(matrix, i);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

int **read_matrix(int *rows, int *cols) {
    int **matrix;
    printf("Inserire la dimensione R delle righe e C delle colonne:\n");
    if (scanf("%d%d", rows, cols) != 2 || *rows <= 0 || *cols <= 0) {
        printf("invalid matrix size\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    matrix = new_matrix(*rows, *cols);
    if (matrix) {
        printf("\n**RIEMPIRE LA MATRICE**\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < *rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < *cols; j++) {
                if (scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]) != 1) {
                    free_matrix(matrix, i);
                    return NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

void printmatrix(int **matrix, int rows, int cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf(" %d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int **matrixprod(int **matrix1, int **matrix2, int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2) {
    if (c1 != r2) {
        printf("matrix geometries are incompatible\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    int **matrix3 = new_matrix(r1, c2);
    if (matrix3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
                int p = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++) {
                    p += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                }
                matrix3[i][j] = p;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix3;
}

int main(void) {
    int r1, r2, c1, c2;
    int **matrix1, **matrix2, **matrix3;
    if (!(matrix1 = read_matrix(&r1, &c1)) || !(matrix2 = read_matrix(&r2, &c2)))
        return 1;
    if (c1 != r2) {
        printf("PROD NON ESEGUIBILE");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n****PROD MATRIX*****\n");
    matrix3 = matrixprod(matrix1, matrix2, r1, c1, r2, c2);
    if (matrix3) {
        printmatrix(matrix3, r1, c2);
        free_matrix(matrix3, r1);
    }
    free_matrix(matrix2, r2);
    free_matrix(matrix1, r1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What a solution! Really thank you man, your solution is the most complete that i've recieved and it's useful for me like a university lesson, your second part of the code is wonderful, thank you for the example and the clear explanation

Answer (score 1):

There are actually various problems that you would need to solve.

Firstly, when declaring arrays like `int a[size]` in C, `size` must be a constant can cannot be a variable because the compiler needs to know its size at compile time. To declare `int matrix1[r1][c1]`, you must either use dynamic allocation or use `int matrix1[MAXR][MAXC]`

Secondly, put h++ at the end of the loop, or h will be equal to r1 at the last execution of the loop.

Thirdly, indentation is very important to make the code readable and maintainable. For other languages such as python, a bad indentation won't work. So indent properly.

Corrected code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXR 50
#define MAXC 50

void printmatrix(int** matrix, int r, int c) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i<r; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j<c; j++) {
            printf("-%d-", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void matrixprod(int** matrix3, int ** matrix1, int ** matrix2, int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2) {
    int i, h, k;
    h = k = 0;
    matrix3[h][k] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<c1; i++) {
        matrix3[h][k] += (matrix1[h][i] * matrix2[i][k]);
    }
    k++;
    while (k<c2) {
        matrix3[h][k] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<c1; i++) {
            matrix3[h][k] += (matrix1[h][i] * matrix2[i][k]);
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (h<r1) {
        k = 0;
        matrix3[h][k] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<c1; i++) {
            matrix3[h][k] += (matrix1[h][i] * matrix2[i][k]);
        }
        k++;
        while (k<c2) {
            matrix3[h][k] = 0;
            for (i = 0; i<c1; i++) {
                matrix3[h][k] += (matrix1[h][i] * matrix2[i][k]);
            }
            k++;
        }

        h++;
    }

}

int main() {
    int i, j, h, k;
    int r1, r2, c1, c2;
    printf("Inserire la dimensione R delle righe e C delle colonne:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r1, &c1);
    int ** matrix1 = (int **)malloc(r1 * sizeof(int*));
    printf("\n**RIEMPIRE LA MATRICE 1 **\n");
    for (i = 0; i<r1; i++) {
        matrix1[i] = (int *)malloc(c1 * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j<c1; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Inserire la dimensione R delle righe e C delle colonne:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r2, &c2);
    int ** matrix2 = (int **)malloc(r2 * sizeof(int*));
    printf("\n**RIEMPIRE LA MATRICE 2 **\n");
    for (i = 0; i<r2; i++) {
        matrix2[i] = (int *)malloc(c2 * sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j<c2; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix2[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int** matrix3;
    matrix3 = (int **)malloc(r1 * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i<r1; i++) {
        matrix3[i] = (int *)malloc(c2 * sizeof(int));
    }
    if (r1 != c2) {
        printf("PROD NON ESEGUIBILE");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n****PROD MATRIX*****\n");
    matrixprod(matrix3, matrix1, matrix2, r1, c1, r2, c2);
    printmatrix(matrix3, r1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

The free functions are omitted.

Comment: *int a[size] in C, size must be a constant* not anymore! C99 added VLAs for this very purpose. Support for VLAs has become optional in C11 because some major C compilers never fully implemented support for them (notoriously Microsoft's). The OP's code uses VLAs and compiles so we should assume his compiler supports them

Comment: *you cannot use sizeof(*matrix3) or sizeof(*matrix3[i]) because matrix3 is uninitialized and accessing *matrix3 would be greeted with a Memory Access Violation.* this statement is **completely incorrect**! the OP's approach to memory allocation is actually very good, but he should check for potential `malloc` failure.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I just pointed it out because it doesn't look good to me, but it seems that it is valid!

Comment: Really thank you, with your solution i managed to resolve lot of my other problems, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did this exercise too. I can add comments, if you are needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXR 50
#define MAXC 50
typedef struct mtrx {
    int **values;
    int rows;   
    int cols;   
} mtrx;

void free_values_memory(mtrx *matrix); 
void error_exit(char *message); 
void allocate_memory_for_values(mtrx *matrix); 
mtrx multiply_mtrxs(mtrx *matrix_1, mtrx *matrix_2); 
void read_mtrx(mtrx *matrix); 
void print_mtrx(mtrx *matrix); 

int main() {
    mtrx matrix_1;
    mtrx matrix_2;

    read_mtrx(&matrix_1);
    read_mtrx(&matrix_2);

    if(matrix_1.cols != matrix_2.rows)
        error_exit("the number of columns of the 1st matrix must equal the number "
        "of rows of the 2nd matrix.");

    mtrx matrix_product = multiply_mtrxs(&matrix_1, &matrix_2);
    print_mtrx(&matrix_product);

    free_values_memory(&matrix_1);
    free_values_memory(&matrix_2);
    free_values_memory(&matrix_product);
    return 0;
}

void error_exit(char *message) {
    printf("\033[1;31mInput is incorrect:\033[0;0m %s\n", message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void read_mtrx(mtrx *matrix) {
    if(scanf("%d %d\n", &matrix->rows, &matrix->cols) != 2)
        error_exit("not enough values");
    else if(matrix->rows > MAXR || matrix->cols > MAXC)
        error_exit("the size of matrix too large");

    allocate_memory_for_values(matrix);

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < matrix->rows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < matrix->cols; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix->values[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void allocate_memory_for_values(mtrx *matrix) {
    matrix->values = malloc(matrix->rows * sizeof(matrix->rows));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < matrix->rows; i++) {
        matrix->values[i] = malloc(matrix->cols * sizeof(matrix->cols));
    }
}
void free_values_memory(mtrx *matrix) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < matrix->rows; i++) {
        free(matrix->values[i]);
    }
    free(matrix->values);
}

mtrx multiply_mtrxs(mtrx *matrix_1, mtrx *matrix_2) {
    mtrx matrix_product;
    matrix_product.rows = matrix_1->rows;
    matrix_product.cols = matrix_2->cols;
    allocate_memory_for_values(&matrix_product);

    int i, j, k, product;
    for(i = 0; i < matrix_1->rows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < matrix_1->cols; j++) {
            for(k = 0; k < matrix_2->cols; k++) {
                product = matrix_1->values[i][j] * matrix_2->values[j][k];
                matrix_product.values[i][k] += product;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix_product;
}

void print_mtrx(mtrx *matrix) {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < matrix->rows; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < matrix->cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix->values[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

It was tested with following inputs:

```
1 1
2
1 2
2 3
### Answer: ###
4 6
######

2 2
1 2
3 4
2 2
5 6
7 8
### Answer: ###
19 22 
43 50
######

1 3
3 4 2 
3 4
13 9 7 15
8 7 4 6 
6 4 0 3 
### Answer: ###
83 63 37 75
######

2 4
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
3 2
7 8
9 10
11 12
### Answer: ###
58 64 
139 154
######
```